# Is it possible to trigger (ngModelChange) event on a custom child component in a parent via Jest test?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jestjs

I'm working on a unit test in Jest for a component. One of the pieces of functionality I want to verify is that when a child component (which implements `ControlValueAccessor`) rendered in the component modifies its `ngModel` binding and triggers the `(ngModelChange)` event that the parent does the appropriate thing.

For brevity, here's the relevant code of the parent, containing a reference to the child, `<child-component>`:

```
<div>I am the parent component</div>
<child-component
  [(ngModel)]="myModel"
  (ngModelChange)="doAThing($event)"
>
</child-component>
```

In the test I've tried a test like this:

```
it('Binds to the child properly', () => {
  // Bunch of set up where I use Angular's TestBed utility to get a reference to the component
  // and the testing fixture 

  spyOn(component, 'doAThing');
  component.myModel = 'new data';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.doAThing).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But the spy never detects any calls. Now this kind of makes sense because I'm modifying the model directly on the parent which would pass down to the child but *shouldn't* come *back up* to the parent-- you'd end up in a recursive loop in that case.

So then the question is: how do I cause this `<child-component>` to fire off its `(ngModelChange)` event within a Jest test for the parent component?

My only thought from reading the documentation is to [stub out the child component](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#stubbing-unneeded-components) and somehow get a reference to it and manually cause the event to fire. But that seems like a lot of work. Is there an easier path?

Appreciate any thoughts on how best to test this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was on the right track when I posted about [stubbing out the child like is described in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#stubbing-unneeded-components).

I basically had to stub out the child at the top of the parent test like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: '',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: ChildComponent,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    _model: any;
    get model() {
        return this._model;
    }
    set model(val: any) {
        this._model = val || null;
        this.propagateChange(this._model);
    }
    propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
    writeValue(value: any): void {
        this._model = value;
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateChange = changed => {
            return fn.call(this, changed);
        };
    }
    registerOnTouched(): void {}
}
```

The important thing to note is it does have to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` so that we can bind to the `(ngModelChange)` event. This includes the `providers` bit, otherwise Angular won't set it up properly.

Then the test ended up looking something like this:

```
it('Binds to the child properly', () => {
    const childDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
        By.directive(ChildComponent)
    );
    spyOn(component, 'doAThing');

    childDebugElement.componentInstance.model = 'new data';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.doAThing).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

We can use the `debugElement.query` on the `fixture` that we set up using Angular's `TestBed` utility to get a reference to the component we need. Since we provided a stub we can get a reference to the actual component we provided via `childDebugElement.componentInstance`. Then it's just a matter of making sure a call to `propagateChanges` happens. In this case that's via the setter on `model`.

---

I'm not *thrilled* that it requires writing a whole bunch of code for a stub that's only a proxy for the actual component in the parent. But then I guess that's what you get when you basically want an integration test.